# In Java is there a method to find index of a particular string in ArrayList

Tags: java

In Java is there a method to find index of a particular string in ArrayList?
For Example if cities is an array list of 100 cities and I want to find the index of "New York".

Comment: some googling effort would show you that there is an `indexOf` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`indexOf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) method for search in `ArrayList`. If the `String` exists within the `ArrayList`, it returns the index of the `String`, otherwise it returns `-1`.

[This link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_indexof.htm) might be helpful.